# How to program a "wheel" of Bits

Tags: c++

I would like to program a "wheel" with a certain length of Bits and with exactly one Bit set on "true". Once I rotate the wheel (90°) this bit have to rotate too.

Like length := 4:

```
    1             0             0             0             1
  0   0   ==>   0   1   ==>   0   0   ==>   1   0   ==>   0   0
    0             0             1             0             0
```

OR

```
    0001 ==> 0010 ==> 0100 ==> 1000 ==> 0001
```

Once a wheel full rotated an other function has to be called.

What would be a good way to code this?

Comment: Where is your current attempt?

Comment: May take a look at the shift operator

Comment: How about incrementing an int and applying a remainder ?

Comment: Watch out: C++ does not support binary notation, and numbers with a leading zero are considered octal.

Comment: @uliwitness not need binary notation to do binary operation. 0001 is 1.

Comment: @uliwitness also, it does. `0b01010101` is a binary literal.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode I have no current attempt. In the german Wikipedia there are no examples for  "bit rotation" and befor I even didn't knew for what search in Google. That's why I am asking.

Comment: @Quentin Oh right, that's new in C++11. Forgot about that. So yeah, use that if you can rely on your compiler being new enough.

Comment: @Hacketo 1 is the same in every base. But every other number is different. 10 in binary is actually 2 in decimal. So unless you can require C++11, you can not write out binary numbers. Only decimal, octal and hexa-decimal ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know there is only one `1` bit, there's no point in storing all the `0`'s. Just store the position of the `1`.

```
struct Wheel {
    Wheel(int size)
    : _size(size)
    , _onePos(0) {}

    void rotate() {
        ++_onePos;
        if(_onePos == _size) {
            _onePos = 0;
            onFullRotation();
        }
    }

    unsigned int bits() const {
        return 1u << _onePos;
    }

private:
    void onFullRotation() {
        std::cout << "<full rotation>";
    }

    int const _size;
    int _onePos;
};
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/254f6b0aa48b8314)

Answer (score 1):

This operation is known as bit rotation.

```
unsigned rotate_left(unsigned x, unsigned num_bits, int delta) {
    unsigned rdelta = delta % num_bits;
    unsigned mask = (1 << num_bits) - 1;
    return ((x << rdelta) | (x >> (num_bits - rdelta))) & mask;
}
```

This will rotate bitwheel `x` containing `num_bits` bits left by `delta` bits. Negative shifts should also work. The equivalent `rotate_right` function can be obtained by changing `<<` to `>>` and vice versa.

If `num_bits` is 32 and you need this operation to execute very fast, you can use intrinsics for the machine rotate instructions.

Addendum: to test the rightmost (zeroth) bit, of course use:

```
if (x & 1) { ...
```

To test bit N:

```
if (x & (1 << N)) { ...
```

If you need more than 32 bits, use `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` (depends on your platform). If you need an arbitrary number of bits, this solution won't work - you'll need to use something based e.g. on `std::bitset` like in the second answer, or on `vector<bool>`.

Comment: for negative shifts, you can use `(delta % size)` instead of `delta`.

Comment: It's actually implementation dependent, but most implementations will give us what we mean here. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your "wheel" can be represented as a field of bits in your memory.
If the required length is smaller than 64, then you can use any integer type to implement it. it's simple:

```
void shift_clockwise(unsigned long long *wheel, int size) {
    unsigned long long first_bit = (*wheel) & 1ll;
    (*wheel) = ((*wheel) >> 1) & (first_bit << (size-1));        
}
```

If the size is larger, then you can use [`std::bitset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/), for example:

```
void shift_clockwise(std::bitset<wheel_size>& wheel) {
    bool first_bit = wheel.test(0);
    wheel >>= 1;
    set(wheel.size()-1, first_bit);
}
```